# How to get the types right for Swift Dictionary mutable extension to add Int values with different keys

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm using a JSON API that represents a birthday as three separate values in a dictionary. Since the date has to be added to a dictionary in several places in the same way, I wanted to move the code to a `Dictionary` extension.

```
    var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
    // other keys are set ....
    if let birthDate = birthDate,
        let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier:  NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian) {
        let dateComponents = calendar.components([.Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: birthDate)
        dict["birthDay"] = dateComponents.day
        dict["birthMonth"] = dateComponents.month
        dict["birthDay"] = dateComponents.year
    }
    // other keys are set ....
```

This works just fine. However in a `Dictionary` extension, I can't seem to get the types right.

```
    extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible , Value: AnyObject {
        // other type restrictions for Key and Value didn't work
        mutating func addBirthDate(birthDay: NSDate?) {
            if let birthDate = birthDay,
                let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier:  NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian) {
                let dateComponents = calendar.components([.Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: birthDate)
                self["birthDay"] = dateComponents.day
                // Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type `_?`
                self["birthMonth"] = dateComponents.month as Value
                // 'Int' is not convertible to `Value`; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?
                self["birthDay"] = dateComponents.year as NSNumber
                // Cannot assign value of type `NSNumber` to type `_?`
            }
        }
    }
```

I also tried casting `self` with `if let self = self as? [String: AnyObject]` without success.

Restricting the `Dictionary` to only `Int` values, fails because `Int` is a non-protocol type. `IntegerType` didn't work either.

```
extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible , Value: Int
```

But I want to add other types of values to the same dictionary, so just having `Int`s doesn't do it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Casting to `Value` was the right idea. But it needs to be an optional `as? Value`.

```
if let day = dateComponents.day as? Value {
    self["birthDay"] = day
}
```